# Trying to offload long running task from django to a separate thread

Tags: django, python-3.x, multithreading, django-admin

I have a Django 2 app with an action in the admin that takes one to many images and uses the face_recognition project to find faces and store the face information in the database. I would like to offload this action to a different thread. However, in my attempt at starting a new thread, the Django app does not return until all the threads are done. I thought that if I put the long running task in a separate thread, then the Django app would return and the user could do other things with it as the long running process ran in the background.

DocumentAdmin action code:

```
def find_faces_4(self, request, queryset):
     from biometric_identification.threaded_tasks import map_thread_pool_face_finder
     images_to_scan = []
     for obj in queryset:
         # If the object is a Photo with one to many people, send to face recognition
         metadata = DocumentMetaData.objects.filter(document_id = obj.document_id)[0].metadata
         if "Photo Type" in metadata and metadata["Photo Type"] != 'No People':
                 images_to_scan.append(obj)
     map_thread_pool_face_finder(images_to_scan)
```

The code to find the images:

```
def map_thread_pool_face_finder(document_list):
    t0 = timeit.default_timer()       
    pool = ThreadPool()
    pool.map(fftask2, document_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()  
    t1 = timeit.default_timer() 
    logger.debug("Function map_thread_pool_face_finder {} seconds".format(t1 - t0))

def fftask2(obj):
    find_faces_task(obj.document_id, obj.storage_file_name.name, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The find_faces_task does the actual image scanning for faces.

I expected the action to pass off the face finding to separate threads, and return right away while the images are found in the background. The face recognition works, but the Django app is frozen until all the images are found. What am I missing in my understanding of multithreading or my code?

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: The pool.join command tells python to wait until the thread is complete.

Comment: Thanks! I took out that statement, and  there is no more blocking. However, the facial recognition does not run. Nothing happens.

Comment: Was this ever solved?